# Is it ok to eat kimchi that is causing its package to expand?

Tags: storage-lifetime, fermentation, kimchi

For non-fermented foods, I feel like it's obvious that they shouldn't be consumed if they're causing the package they're stored in to expand, even if they're still within the "best by" date. Does this apply to fermented foods like kimchi?

I had some yesterday and, while it's still in date (just), the sealed package was notably "inflated". It popped when opening and the kimchi made a "fizzing" sound for a little while. It didn't smell off and it tasted OK, albeit a little more acidic than usual.  So far I haven't suffered any adverse effects.

I have one tub left. Is this Korean Roulette, or should it be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fresh kimchi will continuously release gas as it continues to ferment; unlike some other fermented foods, it contains active cultures. Commercial kimchi is often packaged with a "gas absorber", but that can only do so much. So yes, it should be fine.